# Stacked histogram with bin heights defined in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'd like to create a stacked histogram out of numpy arrays with entries that are the desired bin heights.

For example I have twelve bins defined by:

```
bins = np.linspace(0,120,13)
```

And I have a few numpy arrays each with twelve elements (1 for each bin):

```
hist1 = [1.1,2.2,3.3,4.4,......,hist1[11]]
hist2 = [9.9,8.8,7.7,6.6,......,hist2[11]]
```

I'd like to turn into a stacked histogram. Is this possible with matplotlib?

Comment: Unfortunately those examples do not help; those arrays have values which get sorted into the appropriate bin. My array values _are_ the bin height.

Comment: See here: http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/bar_stacked.html

Comment: Oh, you can just draw the rectangular patches directly, then --

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The weights parameter will solve this for you.  Put a single data point in each bucket, then control the height by specifying its weight

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

bins = np.linspace(0,120,13)


# my approximation of your example arrays
hist1 = np.arange(1.1,15, 1.1)
hist2 = np.arange(15, 1.1, -1.1)

all_weights = np.vstack([hist1, hist2]).transpose()
all_data = np.vstack([bins, bins]).transpose()
num_bins = len(bins)

plt.hist(x = all_data, bins = num_bins, weights = all_weights, stacked=True, align = 'mid', rwidth = .5)
```

If your bins weren't equally spaced they would start to be different thicknesses but aside from that, this should solve your problem.
[image]