# Creating a Log Histogram Plot with Defined Bins and Heights using Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I am trying to plot some neutron flux energy spectrum results outputted from MCNP. I've gotten a good idea on how to appropriately set the weights using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29711612/stacked-histogram-with-bin-heights-defined-in-numpy-array). Here is the data I'm currently working with.

```
Intensity = [0.0, 61798.50000000001, 18032.899999999998, 27729.300000000003, 16493.0, 20837.0, 27507.299999999996, 34675.899999999994, 102999.0, 135864.0, 250667.99999999997] #Fluxes
Energy = [0.0, 1e-07, 1e-06, 1e-05, 0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1.0, 10.0, 20.0] #Energy MeV
plt.hist(energy,  weights=intensity, log=True)
plt.show()
```

When I plot this, only three bars shows up. It looks like the histogram is missing some of the values due to the orders of magnitude for each bin. Is there a simple way to set the bins to be logarithmic as well?

EDIT:

I've tried including `ax.set_xscale('log')`

Here is what the plot looks like currently.

[Plot of Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4gJJ.png)

I'm not sure why my weights are only being used to create three bins, and the heights don't seem to match up to any of the intensity values. Thoughts?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck. What did you try?

Comment: I found that it was grouping my magnitudes in a weird way as I was using  ```bins = len(energy)``` where I only needed to set ```bins=energy``` directly to specify the bins. The plot now looks great!